# Compile AWS SDK c++ fail

Tags: aws-sdk-cpp

I download the 1.2.4 version AWS SDK C++ in my one EC2 server(Amazon Linux AMI)
Then I try to follow README.md to compile it,

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release /home/ec2-user/aws-sdk-cpp-1.2.4/
```

I got many error, like below:

```
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeVERSIONInformation.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMake1.2.4Information.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeLANGUAGESInformation.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_VERSION_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_1.2.4_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_LANGUAGES_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Pulse audio header files have been detected, included pulse audio as a possible sound driver implementation.
CMake Error at cmake/utilities.cmake:100 (export):
  export Unknown arguments.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  aws-cpp-sdk-text-to-speech/CMakeLists.txt:126 (do_packaging)

CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeVERSIONInformation.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMake1.2.4Information.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeLANGUAGESInformation.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_VERSION_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_1.2.4_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_LANGUAGES_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeVERSIONInformation.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMake1.2.4Information.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeLANGUAGESInformation.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_VERSION_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_1.2.4_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_LANGUAGES_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeVERSIONInformation.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMake1.2.4Information.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeLANGUAGESInformation.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_VERSION_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_1.2.4_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_LANGUAGES_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeVERSIONInformation.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMake1.2.4Information.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeLANGUAGESInformation.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_VERSION_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_1.2.4_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_LANGUAGES_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeVERSIONInformation.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMake1.2.4Information.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeLANGUAGESInformation.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_VERSION_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_1.2.4_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_LANGUAGES_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ec2-user/aws-sdk-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

who know how to resolve it

thanks

Comment: after install CMake new version. it is OK now